# SQL WITH PYTHON GIVING ERROR :- Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I am trying to run sql commands with python, but for some reason, its giving me error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". Tried everything but still didn't work. This is my code:-

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="###", database="student", auth_plugin="mysql_native_password")
cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute("insert into student(Rollno, Name, Class, marks) values(1,'carren','1B',100, 5,'john','2A',50)")
```

Comment: You're trying to insert 8 values into 4 columns

Comment: but i want to insert values for 2 rows together

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please correct your tags.

Comment: Youve also tagged SQL Server here; if you're trying to use MySQL libraries with SQL Server you're going to encounter problems.

Comment: already tried, it didn't worked

Comment: A quick look at the documentation would soon resolve your issue.

Comment: "already tried, it didn't worked " already tried what? And what does "it didn't work" mean? Did it throw an error? Inserted the wrong number of rows? Please be precise.

Comment: it gave me same error:- Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Then provide the correct number of values to match your columns... the error is telling you the issue. And look up the documentation for the database you are using for how to provide "values".

Comment: Its working when i insert only one row, but i want to insert 2 rows

Comment: Then look into how to insert multiple rows at a time. It's really hard to correct this kind of misunderstanding where you think the db driver will somehow know that it needs to fold the 8 inputs you give it into two rows of 4 values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you need to separate the values:

```
cursor.execute("insert into student(Rollno, Name, Class, marks) values(1,'carren','1B',100), (5,'john','2A',50)")
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted.  That IS completely valid MySQL syntax, and it DOES solve the original problem.

Comment: That's absolutely false.  You need ROW if you are using the VALUES in another statement, but the syntax here has ALWAYS been valid for INSERT INTO.  Always.  https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-multiple-rows/

Comment: @TimRoberts my bad... I must have originally used it within a sub-query or similar where it required `ROW` and then never tried without. Odd to have the syntax change based on where its used.